# Jquery UI dialog too much recursion problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, recursion, jquery-ui-dialog

Below code gives Too much recursion error in Jquery ui dialog

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
                   close:function(){
                       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
    });
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Infinite recursion is happening here.
Just change

```
close:function(){
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
```

to

```
 close:function(){

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because you have infinite recursion.

```
close:function(){
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
```